# C++ nested if statments, basic currency exchange

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have a simple C++ issue with my if statements, the program runs the values as the initial if parameters rather than performing the else if. Also I tried to code so that if the result of the function equaled 1 it would type out a grammatically correct statement is there a better way of doing that other than using another if statement?

```
int main()
{
cout << "Please type out amount and currency type to convert to dollars.\n";
double val1;
string currency;
double result = 0;
cin >> val1 >> currency;
if (currency == "yen" || "y")
{
    result = val1/100;
    if (result == 1) {
        cout << "You have " << val1 << "yen which equals \n"
            << result << ", dollar.";
    }
    else
    cout << "You have " << val1 << "yen which equals \n"
        << result << ", dollars.";
}
else if (currency == "euros" || "e")
{
    result = val1*1.25;
    if (result == 1) {
        cout << "You have " << val1 << "euros which equals \n"
            << result << ", dollar.";
    }
    else
        cout << "You have " << val1 << "euros which equals \n"
        << result << ", dollars.";
}
else if (currency == "pounds" || "p")
{
    {
        result = val1 *1.2;
        if (result == 1) {
            cout << "You have " << val1 << "pounds which equals \n"
                << result << ", dollar.";
        }
        else
            cout << "You have " << val1 << "pounds which equals \n"
            << result << ", dollars.";
    }
}
else
    cout << "I didn't understand, please try again.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you type `if (currency == "yen" || "y")`, you probably want it to mean "if `currency` is equal to `"yen"` or if it is equal to `"y"`, do something".

However, this is not what your if-statement actually does. The if-statement

`if (currency == "yen" || "y")`

first tests if the string `currency` is equal to `"yen"`, and if not, it evaluates `"y"` by itself and checks if it is equal to true.

In this case, "y" will be truncated to a `bool`, meaning that it will evaluate to `true` (because `"y"` is not equal to `0`). As a result, your first if-statement will *always* evaluate to true!

To fix this, replace your if-statement with
`if (currency == "yen" || currency == "y")`.

---

For your second question, you could use a conditional operator, which works as so:

`cout << "You have " << (val1 == 1 ? "thing" : "things") << endl;`

The conditional in this case is `(val1 == 1 ? "thing" : "things")`. It checks if `val1 == 1`, then returns `"thing"` if it is `true` and `"things"` otherwise.

Comment: There's a problem with testing floats for equality. The `== 1` will basically never hit, except for very special conditions. You have `1.0000000000001 dollars`.

Comment: Thanks very much Telescope, those were the two things that I needed.

Comment: No problem. If you experience these problems in the future, you should try inserting debug prints or using a debugger, which can help you narrow down issues very quickly. Good luck with your program.